# What's `conv_layer.get_weights()[1]`?

Tags: keras

I have a Keras conv2D layer `conv_layer` in a model. `type(conv_layer.get_weights())` is `list` and its length is 2.

I think there are kernel weights in `conv_layer.get_weights()[0]`.

What's `conv_layer.get_weights()[1]`?

Its shape is (64,).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the biases for each convolutional filter, seems you have 64 filters in that layer.